# invoke a function defined in this angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have  a function defined usign this to call in the model but how can inveoque that function in the controller? Angular generate a error

> TypeError: this is undefined

example code

```
this.addForms = function addForms (param1, param2) {
    //function code
}

function auxFunction () {
  this.addForms (0 , 1);
}
```

Comment: http://alistapart.com/article/getoutbindingsituations

Comment: I think the first "this" and the second "this" don't refer to the same object. The second "this" refers to auxFunction() and the first one to your wrapping object that we can't see. You should store your first "this" in a variable for exemple "self" (var self = this) and set self.addForms = function() and use self.addForms(0, 1).

Comment: @Nephelococcygia thanks  you are right that is the error

Answer (score 0):

```
this.addForms = function addForms (param1, param2) {
    //function code
}

var self = this;  //i.e just answered by @Nephelococcygia 

function auxFunction () {
  self.addForms (0 , 1);
}
```

Comment: It is preferred to add some explanation along with the answer. It will be helpful to others to understand it and solve the problem.

Comment: Explanation is already being given by @Nephelococcygia , I just explained the implementation. I hope you read the comments before solving any problem on stack overflow.

Comment: I'm glad to hearing back from you. it is not possible to predict whether the user is going to read the comments or not. If you [add some explanation along with answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) it ll be helpful for others to understand what you are trying to explain.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Will take care next time.